# datadriven testing using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, data-driven-tests

Im using selenium webdriver for automation testing in my company to automate webapplications, but im using id, xpath and all directly without following any framework , so now im in some prob and have to design the DATA DRIVEN FRAMEWORK .

Please suggest me how to setup DatadrivenFramwework under eclipse.what and all steps to be followed.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use a data-driven framework for your element identifiers (ids and xpaths)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do **data driven testing** without using any framework. For that you can use **JXL API** or **POI API**, with use of these API you can do data driven testing for your web application. It very easy to configure these API with your **Eclipse**.

**Note**:- JXL API is now off dated, it only work with .xls files. POI API works with both .xls & .xlsx file.